# How to use webpack and a custom html template to serve up svg sprites

Tags: webpack, html-webpack-plugin

I have created a custom .html template and I use it with `HtmlWebpackPlugin`. I know I can take regular images and place them inside lodash template tags like this:

```
<img src="<%=require('./src/img/logo.png')%>" alt="Logo" class="header__logo" />
```

This works fine. But how do I do this with svg sprites. My template has many svgs written like this:

```
<button class="nav__btn nav__btn--bookmarks">
    <svg class="nav__icon">
        <use href="src/img/icons.svg#icon-bookmark"></use>
    </svg>
    <span>Bookmarks</span>
</button>
```

I'm trying to use `new HtmlWebpackInlineSVGPlugin()` but with no luck. The final output html file in the dist folder does not change the href attribute to point to the proper location.

Answer (score 0):

Give https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-svg-spritely a try.

It will take a build's incoming SVG files and convert them to a sprite file on disk, that then can be loaded into the document using a injected XHR request.